# Swift: delay notification until other notification finish

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I create class `CurrencyTextField` subclass `UITextField`
It have notification:
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.textDidChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange, object: self)`
In `ViewController` i have `var currencyTextField: CurrencyTextField!`
And it also have `currencyTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(priceTextFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)`
But notification in `CurrencyTextField` is slower than `ViewController`. Is there a way to make notification in `CurrencyTextField` call first?
My only solution is add `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` on `ViewController`

Comment: Why do you need the notification to happen before the action? Can't you just put the code in the notification in the action method?

Comment: Add new TextChangeDelegate with textChanged method. In your textDidChange(_:) call TextChangeDelegate's method. And make ViewController conforms TextChangeDelegate

Comment: @JeremyP i mean here is 1 textField have 2 notification TextDidChange in different place. And I want 1 notification run after the other.

Comment: @tereks thank you. You can put your comment to answer, and i'll accept it.

Comment: You could turn it around. send the action to the instance of your custom field and have the view controller listen for the noitification.

Comment: Or you could sendf the action to the view controller and have it call the method on your field directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new delegate

```
protocol TextChangeDelegate: class {
    func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: TextField)
}
```

In TextField class add following line in textDidChange method

```
@objc
private func textDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textChangeDelegate?.textFieldDidChange(self)
}
```

And then make UIViewController conforms TextChangeDelegate and implement

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: TextField)
```

instead of using

```
currencyTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(priceTextFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```